# Routing in IIS of Windows Server 2022

Tags: iis, routes, windows-server-2022, aspnetcore-environment

My service in AspnetCore 8 has an endpoint like this https://domain/.well-known/est/simpleenroll

My problem is that this endpoint works well in IIS of Windows Server 2019, but it does not work in IIS of Windows Server 2022. In Windows Server 2022, it gets the error message "Service Unavailable". Other endpoints of the service like https://domain/acme or https://domain/scep still work well in IIS of Windows server 2022.

Do you know what causes the issue? Thank you?

Comment: The "Service Unavailable" error message usually means that the server is unable to handle the request for some reason. You need to check Windows Event Viewer for any error messages or warnings related to application pools, IIS, or ASP.NET Core applications.

Comment: I found the issue, in my case, In Windows Server, for some reason, The url https://+:443/.well-known is reserved, and that cause the issue. Depoying the service in a different port like 8443 solve the issue. Thanks

Comment: If you solved the question yourself without help from an answer, please post an answer yourself describing the solution, and then accept it so that future readers can learn from you.